# Swagger create API document: Swagger Editor

Tags: swagger, swagger-editor

I am using swagger for documenting my REST API service.
I have an specific input that I provide to the service. 
I am creating YAML code by myself using swagger editor. The issue I am facing is I am not able to get the input type as XML, it by default takes JSON. 
Is there any issue in my yaml code. The code is given below:

```
swagger: "2.0"
info:
title: Order Update to Dealers
 description: API description in Markdown.
 version: 1.0.0
host: #Host name cannot be specified here
basePath: /api/OrderUpdate
schemes:
  - http
paths:
/GetFullOrderAcknowlegement:
post:
  summary: Returns a list of users.
  consumes: 
    - application/xml 
  produces:
    - text/plain

  parameters:
    - in: body
      name: DealerInput
      description: Optional extended description in Markdown.

      schema:
        properties:
          DealerID:
            type: string
          PONumber:
            type: string
  responses:
    201:
      description: Created
    200:
      schema: {}
      description: OK
    401:
      schema: {}
      description: Authorization information is missing or invalid.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This was a bug](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/issues/4257) in Swagger Editor 3.3.0 and Swagger UI 3.11.0. It was fixed in Editor 3.3.1 and UI 3.12.0 (released on March 4, 2018).

As a workaround, you can [download Editor v3.2.9](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-editor/releases/tag/v3.2.9) and run it locally by opening the `index.html` file in your browser.