# Swagger UI 3.x setting custom content type for body parameter

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui, swagger-2.0, hl7-fhir

**How do I set a content type other than `application/json` for a body parameter in Swagger UI 3.x using a Swagger (Open API) 2.0 YAML definition file?**

My YAML file is as follows, with the consumes element set to `application/json+fhir` and `application/xml+fhir`:

```yaml
swagger: '2.0'
info:
  title: Test
  version: '1.0'
host: 'server.com'
basePath: /fhir
schemes:
  - http
paths:
  /Patient/$getrecordsection:
    post:
      tags:
        - Get record section
      summary: Retrieve a care record section
      consumes:
        - application/json+fhir
        - application/xml+fhir
      produces:
        - application/json+fhir
        - application/xml+fhir
      parameters:
        - in: body
          name: body
          description: ''
          required: true
          schema:
            $ref: '#/definitions/GetRecordSection'
      responses:
        '200':
          description: OK
        '400':
          description: Bad request
definitions:
  GetRecordSection:
    type: object
    properties:
      resourceType:
        type: string
        default: "Parameters"
      parameter:
        type: string
    example:
      resourceType: "Parameters"
      parameter: 
        - name: "patientIdentifier"
          valueIdentifier: 
            system: "http://fhir.provider.net/Id/patient-identifier"
            value: "9999999999"
        - name: "recordSection"
          valueCodeableConcept: 
            coding:
              - system: "http://fhir.provider.net/ValueSet/record-section"
                code: "ALL"
    xml:
      name: Parameters
```

However, the Swagger UI only shows `application/json` as the body parameter content type:

[image: Swagger UI screenshot]

I'm using the current latest Swagger UI build - 3.11.0.

This is a problem with Swagger UI, rather than the Swagger Editor (though I know the two share a significant number of components), and so the root cause could be the same.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Swagger create API document: Swagger Editor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48982473/swagger-create-api-document-swagger-editor)

Comment: It's a bug introduced in the latest release of the Swagger Editor. See the linked Q&A. ^^

Comment: This is an issue with Swagger UI rather than the Swagger Editor, though I know the two share a significant number of components, and so the root cause could be the same.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug in the 3.11.0 version of Swagger UI, using Swagger/Open API 2.0:

https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/issues/4257

Comment: Fixed in Swagger UI 3.12.0 (released on March 4, 2018).